# RadioButtons CheckedChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have 20 radiobuttons on the page and I want to know which one of them was clicked.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button newBTN = new Button();

    newBTN.Text = "Button 1";
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newBTN);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
       RadioButton r = new RadioButton();
       r.ID = i.ToString();
       r.CheckedChanged += RadioButton1_CheckedChanged;
       PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(r);
    }
}
```

New Updated code.. NOTE: THE CODE DOESNT RELATE TO THE ABOVE CODE.

```
      public List<int> ThreadID2Treat { get { return ViewState["Checked"] == null ? null : (List<int>)ViewState["Checked"]; } set { ViewState["Checked"] = value; } }
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
var rad = (CheckBox)sender;
int threadID = int.Parse(rad.ID.ToString());
ThreadID2Treat.Add(threadID);
```

}

```
public void DeleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in ThreadID2Treat)
    {
        UsefulStaticMethods.DeleteThreads(item);
    }
}
```

How do i find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rad = (RadioButton)sendder;
Response.Write("RadioButton Id :" + rad.Id.ToString());
```

You could try the above.

Update : 
To get all select radio buttons in PlaceHolder make sure the AutoPostBack is not set on the radio buttons. You dont need to add CheckChanged Event. "r.CheckedChanged += RadioButton1_CheckedChanged;" <= remove.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var control in placeHolder1.Controls)
    {
        var rad = control as RadioButton;
        if (rad != null)
        {
            if (rad.Checked)
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("Radion Button Checked : {0}", rad.ID));
        }
    }

    Response.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: What i check several of them altogether, say 4 of them.. how can i then write them all on the screen?

Comment: I would suggest you use a checkboxlist then.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant,, when does that control fire?... the last radiobox i click.. then its event fires.. can i put all the strings in a collection as a list and then iterate over them to print all.. so if i click radio button 1 , i can put it into a list, and if i click radio button 2, could i add it to a list too?

Comment: Give me two minutes and i'll update the answer for on how to do it.

Comment: So, if i click multiple times.. lets say, i check 5 radiobuttons will 5 radio buttons fire after the page_load method and then the button event?

Comment: No, the way I've done it above is you don't fire the CheckChanged event when you click on the Radio button, because you want to see all the radio buttons selected. Only once you click on your button will you run the code above, this will give you all the checked radio buttons.

Comment: oooh.. Thanks i cant use this:  public List<int> ThreadID2Treat { get { return ViewState["Checked"] == null ? null : (List<int>)ViewState["Checked"]; } set { ViewState["Checked"] = value; } } .. I just put all the buttons into the list..see my code above

Answer (score 2):

With the parameter `sender` you have a direct reference to the event-source control.

```
var rb = (RadioButton)sender;
```

If you want to trigger this event and the postback directly, you must set the RadioButton's `AutoPostBack`-Property to `true`.

Comment: When exactly does the checkedchange event fire.. I dont see full post back when i check it?

Comment: You must set `AutoPostback` to `true`.

Comment: I know, I dont want to... when does that event fire.. after page_load..right

Comment: @Dmitry: yes, events are handled after page_load and before load_complete. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events) for futher informations on the Page-Lifecycle.

Comment: I think the button event fires before the radiobox..or am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is RadioButton)
        {

            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
            //Code to use radioButton's properties to do something useful.
            // get the radio button by its ID
            string id = radioButton.ID;  



        }
    }
```

Comment: Does that event fire before or after the Page_Load?

Comment: Can i know if that event fires after the button click event that generates the full postback/?

Comment: This event will fire After the Page_Load.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
RadioButton r = sender as RadioButton;
Response.Write(r.Id);
```

Comment: r.ID, he hasn't set the controls name.

Comment: There is no full postback when i check..right..!?!? when i click the button then there is the postback..And then i get the value of the ID..am i right?

Comment: If you need to do a Postback while clicking on Radio button, you need to set the autoPost back property to true.

Answer (score 0):

Cast sender as RadioButton:

```
RadioButton r = sender as RadioButton;
if(r != null)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```